# httpauthhandler proceed set max attempts

Tags: android, http-authentication

i've got a problem with httpAuthHandler if i'm calling this

```
httpAutHandler.proceed(field_username.getText().toString(), field_password.getText().toString());
```

It just works fine but when i submit a wrong password to SAP my account gets blocked/disabled because handler.proceed is trying the wrong password more than three times!

My question is: **Can i set max attempts to httpAuthHandler.proceed(String uname, String passwd);**?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create

```
private int count = 0
```

and then in the new WebViewClient() you need to do the following:

```
@Override
public void onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(WebView view, HttpAuthHandler handler, String host, String realm) {
  count++;
  if (count >= 3) {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Login Failed. Please Try Again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

  } else {
    handler.proceed("here your username", "here your password");
  }
}
```